# Python + Pyglet: Efficiently updating the image used by a sprite

Tags: python, pyglet

As the title says. Using batch drawing I get really good performance, even with 4096 sprites. However, since my sprites need to change their underlying image I run into issues with performance. I'm pretty sure I'm doing something silly here, since I specifically created a grid/sprite sheet to handle this effectively. But, of course, I never really use it in any effective manner. I might as well have had 5 different images.

What I really want is to keep the underlying sprite image constant, but shift the visible part based on the "food" metric. Here's the code:

```
import sys, pyglet, random, time

# Constants.
WIDTH         = 1280
HEIGHT        = 960
TARGET_FPS    = 60
GROWTH_CHANCE = 0.1


fps = 0
screen = pyglet.window.Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
random.seed(time.time())


# Here we load universal assets, images, sounds, etc.
grass_tiles_img  = pyglet.image.load('grass_tiles.png')
grass_tiles_grid = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(grass_tiles_img, 1, 5)

# Sprite batches.
grass_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()


class GrassTile:
    '''Define a grass tile which cows can graze on.'''
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, food):
        self.food = food
        self.sprite = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(grass_tiles_grid[0], x, y,
                                            batch=grass_batch)
    
    
    def draw(self):
        grid_index = (self.food // 20)
        self.sprite.image = grass_tiles_grid[grid_index]
        return self.sprite
        
        
    def grow(self):
        if random.random() < GROWTH_CHANCE:
            self.food = min(self.food + 1, 99)


@screen.event
def on_close():
    sys.exit()

@screen.event
def on_draw():
    # Clear the screen.
    screen.clear()
    
    # Draw grass.
    grass_sprites = []
    for grass in grass_tiles:
        grass_sprites.append(grass.draw())
    grass_batch.draw()
    
    # Draw FPS counter.
    label = pyglet.text.Label('FPS: ' + str(fps), 'Times New Roman', 12, 10, 10)
    label.draw()


def grow_grass(dt):
    for grass in grass_tiles:
        grass.grow()


def calculate_fps(dt):
    global fps
    fps = round(min(pyglet.clock.get_fps(), TARGET_FPS))



grass_tiles = [GrassTile(20 * i, 15 * j, 0) for j in range(64) for i in range(64)]
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(grow_grass, 1 / TARGET_FPS)
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(calculate_fps, 1 / TARGET_FPS)

pyglet.app.run()
```

And here's the image so you can run the code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByJTL.png

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the image change during grass.grow()?

You don't need to do anything to the grass in the draw phase except draw the batch. Setting the image of a sprite isn't a draw operation, it just changes texture coordinates.

```
    def grow(self):
        if random.random() < GROWTH_CHANCE:
            self.food = min(self.food + 1, 99)
            grid_index = (self.food // 20)
            self.sprite.image = grass_tiles_grid[grid_index]
```

You also shouldn't be recreating the label every draw frame. Create the label beforehand and just update the text. `label.text = f'FPS: {fps}'`